# How to require dependencies in Java?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependency-management

I am used to tools like composer and npm and bower, where I require my dependencies from centralized repositories. (And for ruby there is bundler, and python has pip.)

Currently though, I am working with jar files and the process of setting them up seems jarring. I have to download them, set them up in the project (I am using IntelliJ IDEA, yet it would be similar to eclipse or netbeans).

I am looking for a way to just say "require library x at version y", and have commands to install and update them.

It seems that maven or gradle do some of that work, yet I am bit confused as they are described as build tools.

I don't want to *build* my application, I just ease dependency management so not to rely on some donwloaded jar files.

Does such a centralized repository exist? What is the de-facto standard? (Used by most people, i.e. composer has made pear obsolete) and how would I set it up?

What is more fit to manage dependencies and how would I do so?

Comment: this question is either too broad or looking for external pointers (documentation, tutorials) or opinion based (you could even just use Ivy and not maven), in any of the three cases, eligible for closure

Comment: Contrary to javascript, you need to compile and build Java applications, that is a good reason to have build and dependency management in the same tool. And the integration with most IDEs is good (or good enough), so it doesn't even get in the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start with the easy question: yes there is a central repository where (almost) everything can be found: http://search.maven.org/
Some companies host their own repository in addition to that. For example [JBoss](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/MavenRepository).

There is also the [Sonatype repository](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html) if you want to host some open source software yourself.

The respository is a simple file structure which contains the jar files and some xml metadata. The layout comes from the maven world but almost any java build system has some way to retrieve artifacts from maven central.

The whole dependency resolution is a bit different to what you know from npm. There every package you depend on has its own dependencies. Some of them might conflict. In the java world these transitive dependencies need to be matched - a common version needs to be identified. This is usually done by the build system. So your "require" is a dependency which means that jar will end up in the classpath and the classes will therefore be available for your code. There is no dynamic in that process out of the box (adding jars into the classpath after your started the jvm).

The dependencies are configured in the pom.xml (if you use maven) the build.gradle file (should you go towards gradle). There is also sbt or Ivy+Ant.

Usually your artifact resolution system will also run the build. This makes sense as you need to define the classpath to compile your java sources. If you would use these tools just to copy that jar files you would still need to find a way to pass all those into the compiler. Which is boring after the 3rd dependency.

Maven comes from the convention over configuration section. See the [5 Minute tutorial](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html). The Intellij integration is very good.

Gradle uses Groovy (a java vm based scripting language) to achieve similar goals but is more open of what happens. But this makes integration in and IDE more difficult - depending on how creative you are with your builds. The [gradle user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide) is a quite good place to start.

There is also Ant+Ivy. Ant is a simple build system where you define tasks. Ivy adds dependency resolution to it.

Not to never have mentioned this: sbt (mostly from the Scala world) or leiningen (mostly clojure) - all JVM based languages.

My recommendation would be maven - it requires a simple pom.xml where you can add dependencies - compile will run out of the box if you follow its directory structure convention - which is quite common in the java world to do. And most IDEs will just work. Should your build require more sophisticated build steps gradle has a good migration path.

The 5 minute tutorial above uses an archetype (project template in maven) to get you started. If you have done that you should be able to just open that folder in IntelliJ and continue from there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such a centralized repository (Maven Central). Use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/).

> Apache Maven is a software project management and comprehension tool.
>   Based on the concept of a project object model (POM), Maven can manage
>   a project's build, reporting and documentation from a central piece of
>   information.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to *build* my application, I just ease dependency management so not to rely on some donwloaded jar files.

Eventually you'll want to build your application anyways, so why not use a build system that supports dependency management? There are pure dependency managers as well (e.g. Apache Ivy) but why not use a fully fledged build tool that makes integration easier?

> Does such a centralized repository exist? What is the de-facto standard? (Used by most people, i.e. composer has made pear obsolete) and how would I set it up?

There are several centralized repositories, one of the most common being [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/)

> What is more fit to manage dependencies and how would I do so?

You can use any build tool which fits your needs and supports this. 3 of them are Maven, Apache Ivy and Gradle. Just pick one and read its doc.

Answer (score 0):

Maven does exactly that. It is a complete build tool, dependency managment is one of the parts. maven uses a central repository, you can have your own or use any repo out there.